# Seq.cast tuple values from obj to string

Tags: casting, f#, tuples, boxing, seq

What is the nice and working way of doing a cast like this?

```
seq { yield (box "key", box "val") }
|> Seq.cast<string*string>
```

Since this looks extremely ugly:

```
seq { yield (box "key", box "val") }
|> Seq.map (fun (k,v) -> k.ToString(), v.ToString())
```

As well as this:

```
seq { yield (box "key", box "val") }
|> Seq.map (fun (k,v) -> unbox<string>(k), unbox<string>(v))
```

Is there a way to "unbox" a tuple into another tuple?

Comment: just factor it out in an unBoxString (k,v) function. And you can call .ToString() directly on the boxed object.

Comment: thank you for suggesting, but I can not call `ToString()` on the boxed tuple, since I would get a string representation of it. And I want to get a tuple of two strings instead.

Comment: Yes, of course. I meant it like in Mark's answer, where the string function is used. You would need to call it on each boxed object, which you already do. I think when it feels "ugly" it's easy to write a one liner. Having many helper functions is idiomatic. The answer is a good example of that.

Comment: Oh, I got it. I can always write a oneliner, but I prefer to use the existing ones. And in this case I though there might be one. Looks like no luck.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could write it slightly nicer as:

```
seq { yield (box "key", box "val") }
|> Seq.map (fun (k, v) -> string k, string v)
```

Imagine, however, that you have a `Tuple2` module:

```
module Tuple2 =
    // ... other functions ...

    let mapBoth f g (x, y) = f x, g y

    // ... other functions ...
```

With such a `mapBoth` function, you could write your cast as:

```
seq { yield (box "key", box "val") } |> Seq.map (Tuple2.mapBoth string string)
```

There's no `Tuple2` module in *FSharp.Core*, but I often define one in my projects, containing various handy one-liners like the one above.

Comment: `string k, string v` already looks a bit better. Since in my case it's just a build script, I don't think I would create a module for that, I will just go with the first suggested option.